# CakePHP - Relação 1~n

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Boa noite, estou com dificuldade no em CakePHP 3 e o problema é o seguinte:

> Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (, ), expecting (idstorie, users_iduser)

- O sistema deve adicionar uma "Storie" ao BD, nisso ela deve gerar automaticamente o seu ID (Auto_Implement) e pegar o ID do usuário que está logado.

---

**TEMPLATE/STORIES/ADD**

```
<nav class="large-3 medium-4 columns" id="actions-sidebar">
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li class="heading"><?= __('Actions') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Stories'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="stories form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create($story) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Story') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('title');
            echo $this->Form->input('content');
            echo $this->Form->input('users_iduser',['value'=>$authUser['iduser'],'type'=>'hidden']); //essa linha pega o usuário da sessão que carrega ao logar.
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

---

**CONTROLLER/STORIESCONTROLLER**

```
public function add()
    {
        $story = $this->Stories->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Stories->patchEntity($story, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Stories->save($story)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The story has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The story could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('story'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['story']);
    }
```

---

**TABLE/STORIESTABLE**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class StoriesTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('stories');
        $this->displayField('title');
        $this->primaryKey(['idstorie', 'users_iduser']);

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('idstorie')
            ->allowEmpty('idstorie', 'create');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('title', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('title');

        $validator
            ->requirePresence('content', 'create')
            ->notEmpty('content');

        $validator
            ->integer('users_iduser')
            ->allowEmpty('users_iduser', 'create');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

---

**ENTITY/STORY**

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Story extends Entity
{

    public $belongsTo = array('User'); 

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'idstorie' => false,
        'users_iduser' => false
    ];
}
```

---

**Desde já agradeço.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[RESOLVIDO]** - Refiz todo o banco de dados do zero.

> **O erro era**: Cannot insert row, some of the primary key values are missing. Got (, ), expecting (idstorie, users_iduser)

O problema se dava pois eu gerei o banco de dados com o **MySQL Workbench** baseado no meu projeto, e as configurações estavam conflitando com o **BAKE**(gerador de código do CakePHP).

- Dica para quem estiver começando com CAKE:

> **Faça tudo na mão, não dependa de ferramentas, assim você saberá exatamente onde está o erro, e não passará pelo mesmo problema que eu. Perdi quase 2 dias com este erro.**

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém se depare com esse tipo de erro, em uma relação ManyToMany, deixe explícito quais as chaves estrangeiras da Tabela de ligação nas Classes Table. Por exemplo (em uma relação ManyToMany entre as Tabelas Usuario e Alerta (sem usar convenção plural do cake)):

```
class AlertaTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->belongsToMany('Usuario', [
                                         'joinTable' => 'alerta_usuario', 
                                         'foreignKey' => 'alerta_id'
                                        ]
                            );
    }
}
```

E na Classe UsuarioTable:

```
class UsuarioTable extends Table
    {
        public function initialize(array $config)
        {
            $this->belongsToMany('Alerta', [
                                        'joinTable' => 'alerta_usuario', '
                                        foreignKey' => 'usuario_id'
                                        ]
                            );
        }
    }
```

Isso deve resolver o problema. Lembrando que não é necessário criar a Classe Table para a tabela de ligação, Cake resolve isso para você.